I want to redirect all 404 errors to specific path (example.com/not-found) in Laravel 11
I want to redirect all 404 erros to /not-found using laravel 11.
ex:
example.com/not-found-page redirect to example.com/not-found
example.com/another-not-found-page redirect to example.com/not-found
// Define the fallback route to redirect to /not-found
Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect('not-found');
});

// Define the /not-found route
Route::get('not-found', function () {
    abort(404);
});


The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#fallback-routes

You forgot the URL slash. The helper function, redirect($url), takes the URL you want to redirect to. Read more about Laravel Redirects here.
Redirect to URL
// Define the fallback route to redirect to /not-found
Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect('/not-found'); // Add forward slash here
});

// Define the /not-found route
Route::get('not-found', function () {
    abort(404);
});

Redirect to a Named Route
You can also redirect to a named route, by passing in a name of the route you wish to redirect users to.
// Define the fallback route to redirect to /not-found
Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect()->route('not-found'); // Use named route here
});

// Define the /not-found route
Route::get('not-found', function () {
    abort(404);
})->name('not-found'); // Name the route here;

